# How to change url usinh .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

this is my wordpress site url link `https://css-tricks.tech/?name1=acumen-capital&name2=aasmaa-securities`, this is my Wordpress `.htaccess` code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want change url like this `https://css-tricks.tech/?name1=acumen-capital&name2=aasmaa-securities`
to this `https://css-tricks.tech/acumen-capital-vs-aasmaa-securities`.

So, what do I have to change in wordpress?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Keep in mind that a htaccess won't modify the links that your application prints

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-vs-([^/]*)$ /?name1=$1&name2=$2 [QSA,L]  # New rule
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```